# How to gradient fill an SVG from an external stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, svg, radial-gradients

I love external stylesheets and want to be able to style any SVG graphics via an external sheet. I can declare single colour stroke and fill for my SVG logo but I want a gradient fill. I've tried a view things but can't get it to work right. Can someone help me figure out how to make it work?

I'm not sure how to put a code snippet considering I'm discussing *external* code, not *inline*, so here's a link to the SVG logo in question and its matching external stylesheet.

Actual logo I'm trying to recreate in SVG (PNG):

[image: Cafe Logo]

SVG logo: http://www.cafenocturne.com/testpage/images/svg/CafeLogoSVG.svg

Stylesheet: http://www.cafenocturne.com/testpage/css/CafeLogoSVG.css

There are some commented-out notes to make sure I don't lose the gradient code I'm trying to implement so I apologize that the CSS file is a mess. Once I can get it to work right, I won't *need* to keep notes there.

So how do I achieve this?

Comment: SVG elements don't support the background CSS property. You'd need to do it via an SVG pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add the gradient to your SVG file, and change the stop-color from CSS:

```css
#color1 {
  stop-color: red
}
#color2 {
  stop-color: blue
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <linearGradient id="lg">
    <stop id="color1" offset="0" />
    <stop id="color2" offset="1" />
  </linearGradient>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="45" fill="url(#lg)" />
</svg>
```

if you need more control of your gradients, you could specify gradients in a seperate file (say 'myGradients.svg')

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <linearGradient id="g1">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="red"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="blue"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <linearGradient id="g2">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="green"/>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="yellow"/>
  </linearGradient>
</svg>
```

now in your css you can do

```
.logo {fill: url('myGradients.svg#g2');}
```

unfortunately this **doesn't work in chrome** :-(

alternatively you can have a copy of your gradient collection in your logo file or html, and still style it with css

```css
.color1 {
  stop-color: green
}
.color2 {
  stop-color: yellow
}
#logo1 {
  fill: url(#g1)
}
#logo2 {
  fill: url(#g2)
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="0" height="0">
  <linearGradient id="g1">
    <stop offset="0" class="color1" />
    <stop offset="1" class="color2" />
  </linearGradient>
  <radialGradient id="g2">
    <stop offset="0" class="color1" />
    <stop offset="1" class="color2" />
  </radialGradient>
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100">
  <circle id="logo1" cx="50" cy="50" r="45" />
</svg>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100">
  <circle id="logo2" cx="50" cy="50" r="45" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Very nice! But otherwise, there's currently no way to control the size and colours of an SVG externally in a CSS file?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but of course you can change the color of an SVG from an extenal stylesheet. The size of an SVG is usualy changed by its container, so style these... If i got you totally wrong, please consider opening amother question and attach a simplified testcase or fiddle...

Comment: I specifically mean gradients being specified entirely outside the SVG in an external file, so that I can port the basic shape anywhere and change how many and what kinds of colour stops each instance has using just an external sheet. I may want my logo to have 6 colour stops on one page and maybe only 2 on another. I may want the type of gradient or beginning and ending points (like top or bottom, left or right, which corner, etc.) to be different in many different places. How to do that entirely putside of the SVG file, itself?

Comment: ok, now i get it. i've updated my answer with a second example.

Comment: That looks amazing! So if I have the generic paths of the logo in its SVG file and do a link to its external CSS file, and have, say, a "purple-to-yellow radial gradient top left corner" SVG file and a "green-to-blue left-to-right" SVG file, I can just specifics in the CSS of the SVG to call the specific gradient SVG I built that I want at the time? So like, build several custom gradient SVG files and call them where I want them?

Comment: Exactly! You can have them in separate files or even in one gradient collection file, whatever suits you. But as I mentioned it doesn't work in chrome.

Comment: Crap. And there's no Chrome workaround or you would've mentioned it. To be cross-browser, then, is it better to just do everything inside the SVG file and just have multiple instances like LogoPurple.svg and LogoOrange.svg and include the specifically coloured logo file I want at the time?

Comment: It depends how many different gradient structures you have compared to how many color variations there are. Besides, it might be possible to write a shim for chrome. I will have a look at this later.